# Postgres does not init the database in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create a new postgres database.

Just for starters - creating a new volume:

```
docker volume create test
```

And then starting the image.

```
docker run  -v test:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 nec-postgres
```

Now here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:10.4

ENV POSTGRES_USER=user
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
ENV POSTGRES_DB=smdr

COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Looks simple, and according to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ suppose to create a database, and run the init scripts on that database if the volume is empty.

When I'm starting my image first time I'm getting as expected:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_database.sql
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
```

After the init I'm seeing (again, as expected)

```
2018-06-05 06:55:51.855 UTC [37] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....
2018-06-05 06:55:51.859 UTC [37] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-06-05 06:55:51.863 UTC [37] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 44) exited with exit code 1
2018-06-05 06:55:51.864 UTC [39] LOG:  shutting down
2018-06-05 06:55:51.904 UTC [37] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2018-06-05 06:55:51.971 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2018-06-05 06:55:51.972 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2018-06-05 06:55:51.978 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-06-05 06:55:51.993 UTC [109] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-05 06:55:51 UTC
2018-06-05 06:55:52.000 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Now, no matter what I do my database is empty. I'm not seeing any tables or any data in the database once I connect to it.

I tried with both 10.4 and 10.4-alpine, I tried 9.6-alpine but can't seem to make that thing work.

I Would appreciate any suggestions.

---

**Update #1:**

Here is the full startup log for postgres:

```
root@smdr:/home/smdr/nec# docker logs smdr_nec-postgres.ytyrdw0r2j76aytclj3d9tusj.0vd91n153gxeydsbjp730tlvj
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2018-06-05 16:00:25.543 UTC [37] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-06-05 16:00:25.560 UTC [38] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-05 16:00:25 UTC
2018-06-05 16:00:25.566 UTC [37] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE

CREATE ROLE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_database.sql
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2_indexes.sql
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3_init.sql
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4_functions.sql
CREATE FUNCTION


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/5_roles.sql


2018-06-05 16:00:26.551 UTC [37] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2018-06-05 16:00:26.555 UTC [37] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-06-05 16:00:26.558 UTC [37] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 44) exited with exit code 1
2018-06-05 16:00:26.559 UTC [39] LOG:  shutting down
2018-06-05 16:00:26.612 UTC [37] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2018-06-05 16:00:26.671 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2018-06-05 16:00:26.672 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2018-06-05 16:00:26.679 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-06-05 16:00:26.697 UTC [109] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-05 16:00:26 UTC
2018-06-05 16:00:26.703 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: Do you have SQL files in the same directory as your dockerfile? I believe using the `COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
` implies you do. I would recommend making a db dump of the data you want to add to your database and store it in a db_dump.sql file then upload it with the following command at the end of your dockerfile `ADD db_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Comment: Hi Ludo, thanks. Yes, files are in the same directory. And I can see in the log that postgres executing them.

Comment: @N'urk did you end up solving this? I'm having this problem too.

Comment: Hey @Muppet! See the answer down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that in fact postgres works just fine. The problem was in the name of the database I was connecting to. I was connecting to the database named smdr, but the script run int he postgres database. I'm not sure if it's a bug, I just moved my stuff to postgres database.

Answer (score 1):

## Init seed DB along with postgre docker container

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.5
        # uncomment to maintan persistance
        # volumes:
        # uncomment to maintan persistance
        #    - ~/volumes/jhipster/postgree/postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        # init with the initial sql file
        #    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgree
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
```

**NOTE #1**

Note that you can link multiple scripts into that folder and they will all run (in alphabetical order)

```
volumes:
  - ./init1.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
  - ./init2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-data.sql
```

**NOTE #2**

Make sure you point to a directory and not a file. So instead of referencing the files directly you can mount directory when you have bulk of files

```
volumes:
  - ./path/to/my/host/folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
  - ./path/to/my/host/folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: Thanks. Same deal. I've updated the question so you can see the full log.